# Initial reputation is 1 or 101?

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

When I login for the first time on any Stack Exchange site, my reputation is initially 1 (I started with Stack Overflow). But I saw some people that have 101 reputation when they started using any of these sites (specially when one of my friends started with Stack Overflow).

What's the basis of initial reputation? Why 1 for some users and 101 for others?

Comment: If you have an existing account on another SE site and link it to the new one, you get 100 extra rep (i think).

Comment: (scroll down about half a page, `When a user associates accounts from two or more Stack Exchange network sites, and at least one of those accounts already has 200 or more reputation, every associated account gets a +100 reputation bonus. This bonus is awarded a maximum of one time per account.`)